# Toggle checkbox in Angular JS repeater table by clicking enclosing row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table, angularjs-ng-click

I have a table constructed with ng-repeat, where each row has a checkbox set by a value in the JSON data that's being repeated:

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in tabledata" ng-click="t.isChecked=t.!isChecked">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="t.isChecked"></td>
    <td>{{t.firstName}} {{t.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

I would like a click on the *row* to toggle the checkbox value in that row.  I tried the above, but it does not work.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
ng-click="t.isChecked = !t.isChecked"
```

Exclamation sign should go in front of `t.isChecked`.

Also make sure you stop propagation of the click event on the checkbox itself, otherwise clicking on the checkbox will not allow you to check/uncheck anything.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="t.isChecked" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/KJziWDmlN2gTbthOF4yJ?p=preview

Comment: There is another problem with event propagation, check updated answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the event propagation issue, first time  I've seen it.  Thanks.

Comment: This is because when you click checkbox it will first check it, but after that event will bubble up to the `tr` and execute `t.isChecked = !t.isChecked` code, unchecking it.

Comment: Simple, easy, beautiful! Thank you!